# Безопасно ли хранить информацию в Session? ASP.Net MVC, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, сессия

Добрый день, граждане! 
Работаю, вот, с ASP.Net. Имеется здесь объект, представляющий текущую сессию пользователя, в него можно записывать информацию любых видов и получать по ключу (короче, нечто вроде Dictionary). Но вот безопасно ли это делать? Может ли пользователь перехватить оттуда хранимую информацию? И, если да, какие есть аналоги?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В браузере нету содержимого самой сессии. Пользователю передается только идентификатор сессии, который записывается в куки. Каждый пользователь может спокойно посмотреть свои куки и изменить.

Безопасно ли это? Конечно нет, но безопаснее куков. Все что передается пользователю от сервера или к серверу можно перехватить иди даже проще случай, например, пользователь может скопировать идентификатор сессии и передать его другому человеку.

Главное отличие сессии от куков это то, что при использовании сессий вся информация хранится на сервере, а у клиента имеется только идентификатор. У куков вся информация хранится у клиента.

Так же сессии хранятся определенное количество времени. Настраивается на веб-сервере. Например, если по истечении 20 минут не было обращения, то сессия автоматически удаляется.

Сеансы поддерживают объекты любого типа, включая специальные, создаваемые самим разработчиком типы данных. Управление сеансом не является частью HTTP-стандарта. Поэтому для отслеживания информации сеанса и ее привязки к соответствующему ответу ASP.NET приходится выполнять дополнительную работу. Для отслеживания сеанса используется уникальный 120-битовый идентификатор, который генерируется по патентованному алгоритму. Этот идентификатор является единственным фрагментом информации, который передается между веб-сервером и клиентом.

Так же можно выбрать где хранить объекты сессии. Это может быть объект в памяти, таблицы в б/д с специальным названием **ASPState** или Windows-служба.

---

Подробную информацию о сессиях, как их использовать, настроить или выбрать метод хранения можно узнать на [ProfessorWeb](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/base/level5/5_4.php)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Теперь знаю отличие сессии от куков!